# how can i delete the first element in a string that fits a certain criteria?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

i am making a program that saves a shopping list in a list and i want to make the option to delete **the first** element that fits a certain criteria for example

```
list = [milk,water,bread,milk]
```

then i run a certain function and the user chooses to get rid of 'milk'. that makes the list look like this

```
list = [water,bread,milk]
```

how can i do this? 
ps. i am new to python and i want something simple and easy to read even if it is not effective.
thanks in advance.

**EDIT** 
i dont think its a duplicate as i browsed for a more than 20 minutes trying to find something simular but either the code was not understandable to me or either its not what i was looking for 
**only the first element with the same name will be deleted, if there are more than 1, they will stay in the list**
another example:

```
list = [cheese,milk,water,milk,bread,milk]
```

if user chose milk the list will look like this:

```
list = [cheese,water,milk,bread,milk]
```

Comment: Well not quite a duplicate though. Try this:
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == 'milk':
        del lst[i]
        break

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that's the wrong dup, OP wants to remove the first matched item.

Comment: yes. as i put it in the example only the first element with the same name will be deleted. meaning that if there are more than 1 elements that have the same name the others will stay and the first 1 will be deleted

Comment: Anyway, the answer is to use the lists `remove` method.

Comment: @timgeb: ah, I missed that `milk` was listed twice. The question was worded too vaguely. So the OP wants to remove the first entry of any repeated entries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you are overthinking this, OP wants `mylist.remove('milk')`.

Comment: @timgeb: what if they don't know the name? They'l have to run a count first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters From what I understand the string to be removed comes from user input.

Comment: @timgeb: ah, indeed, then `list.remove()` is all that is needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters timgeb has answered my question. as i said i am new to python so i dont really know a lot of commands. thanks for the help everyone

Comment: By the way, don't use `list` as a variable name, you will shadow the built-in list type.

Comment: @timgeb will never. i programmed before in c and c# and when i was new to programming i have learned this the hard way))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pop`

```
In [106]: l = ['cheese','milk','water','milk','bread','milk']

In [107]: l.pop(l.index("milk"))
Out[107]: 'milk'

In [108]: l
Out[108]: ['cheese', 'water', 'milk', 'bread', 'milk']
```

**OR**

Use `remove(x)`

> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item

```
In [115]: l = ['cheese','milk','water','milk','bread','milk']

In [116]: l.remove("milk")

In [117]: l
Out[117]: ['cheese', 'water', 'milk', 'bread', 'milk']
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER** 
the command i was looking for was `list_name.remove('milk')`. it will delete the first element that fits the criteria and will leave the rest of the list as it was before the change. 
**EXAMPLE**

```
list_name = [tomatoes,water,chocolate,milk,cheese,water]
```

user has chose to delete water and so choice = water. i ran the command specified

```
list_name.remove(choice)
```

after the edit the list will look like this

```
[tomatoes,chocolate,milk,cheese,water]
```